# Regex to conditionally replace Twitter hashtags with hyperlinks

Tags: php, regex, twitter, hashtag

I'm writing a small PHP script to grab the latest half dozen Twitter status updates from a user feed and format them for display on a webpage. As part of this I need a regex replace to rewrite hashtags as hyperlinks to search.twitter.com.  Initially I tried to use:

```
<?php
$strTweet = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w+)/', '\1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23\2">\2</a>', $strTweet);
?>
```

(taken from https://gist.github.com/445729)

In the course of testing I discovered that #test is converted into a link on the Twitter website, however #123 is not.  After a bit of checking on the internet and playing around with various tags I came to the conclusion that a hashtag must contain alphabetic characters or an underscore in it somewhere to constitute a link; tags with only numeric characters are ignored (presumably to stop things like "Good presentation Bob, slide #3 was my favourite!" from being linked).  This makes the above code incorrect, as it will happily convert #123 into a link.

I've not done much regex in a while, so in my rustyness I came up with the following PHP solution:

```
<?php
$test = 'This is a test tweet to see if #123 and #4 are not encoded but #test, #l33t and #8oo8s are.';

// Get all hashtags out into an array
if (preg_match_all('/(^|\s)(#\w+)/', $test, $arrHashtags) > 0) {
  foreach ($arrHashtags[2] as $strHashtag) {
    // Check each tag to see if there are letters or an underscore in there somewhere
    if (preg_match('/#\d*[a-z_]+/i', $strHashtag)) {
      $test = str_replace($strHashtag, '<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23'.substr($strHashtag, 1).'">'.$strHashtag.'</a>', $test);
    }
  }
}

echo $test;
?>
```

It works; but it seems fairly long-winded for what it does.  My question is, is there a single preg_replace similar to the one I got from gist.github that will conditionally rewrite hashtags into hyperlinks ONLY if they DO NOT contain just numbers?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)
```

PHP

```
$strTweet = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/', '\1#<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23\2">\2</a>', $strTweet);
```

This regular expression says a # followed by 0 or more characters [a-zA-Z0-9_], followed by an alphabetic character or an underscore (1 or more), followed by 0 or more word characters.

http://rubular.com/r/opNX6qC4sG <- test it here.

Comment: Ah, perfect!  And remarkably simple too... my brain isn't properly on today.  :p  Many thanks!

Comment: Does this take into account special characters, @Gazler ? Say Will it take words like #Prévoyance ?

Comment: @Jeremy No, but this should do the trick `(^|\s)#(\w*[\S!#]+\w*)`

Comment: "# #abc" results in the match of " #abc" instead of "#abc" (notice the space).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually better to search for characters that aren't allowed in a hashtag otherwise tags like "#Trentemøller" wont work.

The following works well for me...

```
preg_match('/([ ,.]+)/', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have devised this: `/(^|\s)#([[:alnum:]])+/gi`

Answer (score 0):

I found Gazlers [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277114/1050507) to work, although the regex added a blank space at the beginning of the hashtag, so I removed the first part:

```
(^|\s)
```

This works perfectly for me now:

```
#(\w*[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\w*)
```

Example here: http://rubular.com/r/dS2QYZP45n

Comment: Isn't your modified expression the same as `#(\w*\w+\w*)`?

Comment: Either way, Gazler's answer works, it doesn't actually add a blank space at the beginning of the hashtag, rather, it captures two groups, but you only want the 2nd group.