# PHP: How to get this symbol with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to conditionally replace Twitter hashtags with hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277070/regex-to-conditionally-replace-twitter-hashtags-with-hyperlinks)

I'm trying to get the word after the symbol `#`

so the following strings, should all return `stack_overflow`

```
#stack_overflow
hello #stack_overflow
blahblahblah#stack_overflow
```

What would the pattern look like?

Comment: not really... this is more simple.

Comment: There are even simpler duplicates. Be considerate, don't ask for trivial stuff without googling.

Comment: don't you have something more important to do with your life than looking for possible duplicates to a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` matches a "word" character, so:

```
'/#\w+/'
```

`\w` includes lowercase and uppercase letters `a` to `z`, digits, and the underscore. If you need more, use a character set.

Then, if you put it in a group, you can capture it. [Here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/93bMmx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$content = '#stack_overflow
            hello #stack_overflow
            blahblahblah#stack_overflow';
preg_match_all('/\#(?P<name>[a-z_]+?)/Uim', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    var_dump($match['name']);
}
```

That will get you

```
string(14) "stack_overflow"
string(14) "stack_overflow"
string(14) "stack_overflow"
```