# Dynamically replacing @ and # like Twitter

Tags: php, regex

For my Laravel-based site, I need to find `@` and `#` within text content and replace it with a URL, such as a URL pointing at a user's Twitter page.  How can I:

- reliably find these strings within text portions of the HTML
- replace found instances with a URL

Comment: with one of the `_replace()` built-in functions

Comment: I assume you only need to match one word?  Is this in the context of HTML?

Comment: There are many ways to do what you're asking - you should choose one and come back here when you run into problems implementing it.

Comment: Show code which you have tried?

Comment: @RoyalBg That won't work well if he needs to replace in HTML.

Comment: I would need to replace any occurrence of # or @ and if there's multiples I would also have to look up the words in side the @ and # in the database. I'm also working with laravel 4. Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4277070/829533

Comment: @Salim I haven't been able to think of anything I wouldn't think the _replace functions would work because I also have to get the word and look it up the the database. This really stumped me.

Comment: @Brad, why do you think it won't work?

Comment: @zzlalani I'm not using the twitter api to do any of this. I don't need to get twitter profiles.

Comment: I know and you just need to change the urls.. check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19240023/829533

Comment: @RoyalBg There are plenty of cases where you will want an `@` or `#` outside of the context of text within HTML.  Suppose I want to use one of those symbols in my anchor tag `href` attributes.  You cannot blindly find/replace within HTML, and since his question asks about "inserting a link", I'm guessing he is working with HTML.

Comment: `$strTweet = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/', '\1#<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23\2">\2</a>', $strTweet);` in the above code just change the `url` from `http://twitter.com/search?q=%23\2` to your `http://myurl.com/somepage.php?q=%23\2`

Comment: @dragonfire1119 You really need to put the part about looking stuff up in a database in your question.  That is now effectively your entire question.  Replacing strings is trivial, and that's what you originally asked.

Comment: @Brad, it's out of the question scope. The author wants to replace @ and # with link. He can do it with a replace function. Once he try it, he will find out that things which should not be replaced, are being replaced and will write conditions for that. Writing conditions what to be replaced is out of the question "how to" be replaced

Comment: @Brad Yes brad that is correct I'm working with html that's my problem all these answers are good but they all blindly replacing @ and # like the duplication up there. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The code for it is vast. You will have to use ajax here, in the textarea/textbox you will have to use "onkeyup" event, every key pressed have to be compared with "@" or "#" then the next character right after "@" has to be searched in the database.
So lets saw the user has typed "@A" till now and the user aims to type "@Ankur" Then as soon as "A" is typed the ajax script will start searching for users in the database and it is retrieved with the name, url and you just have to echo it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

THis is what you are looking for.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277114/829533

```
$strTweet = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/', '\1#<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23\2">\2</a>', $strTweet);
```

And https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766219/829533

```
$input = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>', $input);
```

Comment: Ya I had to rethink my route but this solved it thanks.

Comment: if this helps and solved the problem you can accept this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Using regex it's rather simple. I would make one function that takes a prefix and replacement, like so.

```
function tweetReplaceObjects($input, $prefix, $replacement) {
    return preg_replace("/$prefix([A-Za-z0-9_-])/", $replacment, $input);
}
```

An example usage would be something like this.

```
$text = 'hey look, it\'s @stackoverflow over there';

// expected output:
// hey look, it's <a href="http://www.twitter.com/stackoverflow">stackoverflow</a> over there
echo tweetReplaceObjects($text, '@', '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$1">$1</a>');
```

Comment: I don't really understand why people can't do what you just did and just help me instead of complaining and directing me to 2 to 3 year old posts. Also nobody read the original question they just wanted to down vote it and edit it. Thanks for the help.