# JavaScript RegExp replace text

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to wrap around a #hashtag with `<a href=''></a>` in a sentence. I created a regular expression `var exp = /#[\w\dğüşçöı]+/gi`.

That expression works perfectly fine but I can't replace a #hey dude! string with

`<a href='hashtag/hey'>#hey</a> dude!`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4u613nh/3/) example.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Convert #hey into `<a href='hashtag/hey>#hey</a>` form.

Answer (score 1):

Surround your word regexp with brackets to make it a capture group that will be recognized by the replacement string as $1:

```
/#([\w\dğüşçöı]+)/gi
```

Comment: Note that this will throw away the # - you'll need to re-include it in the replace text

Comment: Thank you. I'll kindly accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: not now you've included it in the capture group it isn't, but it has been added to your /hashtag/#url though, which isn't what you intended

Comment: @JamesThorpe Is it safe to use '#' in URL?

Comment: depends what the intention of the url is...!  I'd guess in your case probably not.  What this will do is load whatever page is at `/hashtag/` and then try to navigate to the `#hash` anchor on that page, rather than just navigating to the page served by `/hashtag/hash`

Comment: @JamesThorpe Oh yes, that's right. Then I think I'll have to check my URL structure again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63346/discussion-between-emreaydin149-and-james-thorpe).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in a similar PHP-Question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277114/4161041):

```
var raw = "Hello #world! #hey dude!";
var pattern = /#(\w*[a-zA-Z_ğüşçöı]+\w*)/ig;
var replacement = "<a href=\"hashtag/$1\">#$1</a>";
var parsed = raw.replace(pattern, replacement);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3pttLnz/

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's PHP. I'm trying to reduce server's load with doing it with JavaScript. But thank your for finding it. I'll use it for pre-loaded content with PHP.

Comment: Nope, it's JavaScript. I just used the expression from the PHP-Topic. Try my example by clicking jsfiddle-link ;-)

Comment: Oh, selective perception. I thought that's a PHP code when I read PHP-Question :D Didn't read rest of the code.